# Is there a faster or easier method to map financial year?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

In Excel 2013, I have a date range for the product period:

Column A contains Start Date Eg. 01-AUG-2014
Column B contains End Date Eg. 31-JUL-2015

In Column C I need to map the financial year, which should be 2014-15. Financial year starts on April 1 and ends on March 31 the next year.

My data has financial year from 2001-02 to 2015-16, and currently I write lengthy IF, THEN formulas.

Is there any easier way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

This should solve your problem:

```
=CONCATENATE(YEAR(A1);"-";RIGHT(YEAR(B1);2))
=CONCATENATE(YEAR(A1),"-",RIGHT(YEAR(B1),2))
```

I am not sure if you need to use `,` or `;` in your Excel version (depends on the Language setting).

***edit 1:***

```
=CONCATENATE(YEAR(A2),"-",RIGHT(MAX(YEAR(A2)+1,YEAR(B2)),2))
```

***edit 2:***

This will work:

```
=CONCATENATE(YEAR(A2-DATE(YEAR(D10),4,1)+DATE(YEAR(D10),1,1)),"-",RIGHT(MAX(YEAR(A2-DATE(YEAR(D10),4,1)+DATE(YEAR(D10),1,1))+1,YEAR(B2-DATE(YEAR(D10),4,1)+DATE(YEAR(D10),1,1))),2))
```

If we would no have leap years we could write `-90` instead of `-DATE(YEAR(D10),4,1)+DATE(YEAR(D10),1,1)` which would simplify the formula:

```
=CONCATENATE(YEAR(A2-90),"-",RIGHT(MAX(YEAR(A2-90)+1,YEAR(B2-90)),2))
```

Comment: My excel uses comma (,) The year after the hyphen should be incremented by 1, where year is same for start and end date

Comment: I edited the answer. If A1 contains `01-AUG-2014` and B1 `31-JUL-2015` should then be displayed 2014-15 or 2014-16 in C1?

Comment: It works ok for those dates, however for **31-MAR-2014** TO **30-MAR-2015**, it reflects **2014-15**, instead of **2013-14**

Comment: Updated. For clarification: 31-MAR-2014 TO 30-MAR-2015 should display 2013-14; 30-APR-2014 TO 30-MAR-2015 should display 2014-15; But what should **20-MAR-2014** TO **30-MAR-2015** display? **2013-14** or **2013-15**?

Comment: _20-MAR-2014_ TO _30-MAR-2015_ would display `2013-14`

Comment: Sorry ... typo: But what should 20-MAR-2014 TO 30-APR-2015 display? 2013-14 or 2013-15?

Comment: It should display `2013-14`